# How to morph two images in Android/AndEngine

Tags: android, image, graphics, andengine, morphing

I want to know is their any sub-library of Andengine that can morph two different images? or in Android? I have been looking for it but i haven't found anything. Help me out...

Comment: can you describe "morph" a bit? Do you mean the effect in Michael Jackson's Black or White video? Or the liquid metal from Terminator 3? Or just doing an alpha crossfade?

Comment: yes exactly, that MJ's black and white video is morphing...i dont know how to do it in Android (more specifically in andengine)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing native to andengine that will do that.

To morph images, you need a bitmap manipulation library that does that:
[javamorph](http://code.google.com/p/javamorph/)
For example this one.

Then in andengine, you assign a texture to a Sprite, and as the bitmap updates, you will need to update the texture region.

Or, render the morph frames and make an animatedSpritetexture.

Comment: please give me some example of image morphing i don't know how to use this java morph liberary..

Comment: paste your example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779669/how-to-morphing-on-image-in-android

Comment: Sturegon give me some link about morphing