# Android: how to warp images?

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to warp images like this:

[image: Example image]

*Added 08-04-2013*: I used this code but it's not working properly:

```
    private static final int WIDTH = 20;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 20;
    private static final int COUNT = (WIDTH + 1) * (HEIGHT + 1);

    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final float[] mVerts = new float[COUNT*2];
    private final float[] mOrig = new float[COUNT*2];

    private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Matrix mInverse = new Matrix();

    private static void setXY(float[] array, int index, float x, float y) {
        array[index*2 + 0] = x;
        array[index*2 + 1] = y;
    }

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                                 R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        float w = mBitmap.getWidth();
        float h = mBitmap.getHeight();
        // construct our mesh
        int index = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y <= HEIGHT; y++) {
            float fy = h * y / HEIGHT;
            for (int x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x++) {
                float fx = w * x / WIDTH;                    
                setXY(mVerts, index, fx, fy);
                setXY(mOrig, index, fx, fy);
                index += 1;
            }
        }

        mMatrix.setTranslate(10, 10);
        mMatrix.invert(mInverse);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);

        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmapMesh(mBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, mVerts, 0,
                              null, 0, null);
    }

    private void warp(float cx, float cy) {
        final float K = 10000;
        float[] src = mOrig;
        float[] dst = mVerts;
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {
            float x = src[i+0];
            float y = src[i+1];
            float dx = cx - x;
            float dy = cy - y;
            float dd = dx*dx + dy*dy;
            float d = FloatMath.sqrt(dd);
            float pull = K / (dd + 0.000001f);

            pull /= (d + 0.000001f);
         //   android.util.Log.d("skia", "index " + i + " dist=" + d + " pull=" + pull);

            if (pull >= 1) {
                dst[i+0] = cx;
                dst[i+1] = cy;
            } else {
                dst[i+0] = x + dx * pull;
                dst[i+1] = y + dy * pull;
            }
        }
    }

    private int mLastWarpX = -9999; // don't match a touch coordinate
    private int mLastWarpY;

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float[] pt = { event.getX(), event.getY() };
        mInverse.mapPoints(pt);

        int x = (int)pt[0];
        int y = (int)pt[1];
        if (mLastWarpX != x || mLastWarpY != y) {
            mLastWarpX = x;
            mLastWarpY = y;
            warp(pt[0], pt[1]);
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/javamorph/ try this library.

Comment: Whether you have seen this? https://github.com/huntergdavis/Easy_Image_Morph Hope this might help you.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: @NullPonyPointer i added my reserach code but it not give me proper output..

Comment: btw, this is warping and not morphing.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor yes you are right this is warping you have any idea about image warping. if you have please paste some links..

Comment: look once at this http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards may help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9239154/832776

Comment: @OlegVaskevich i already use this code..but not getting proper output..

Comment: You may need to port from other platforms. Take a look at [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), for example.

Comment: have you any idea or code at this time? same que. +1

Answer (score 3):

There is a much easier way than coding you own. See [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

> An extension of LayerDrawables that is intended to cross-fade between
>   the first and second layer. To start the transition, call
>   startTransition(int). To display just the first layer, call
>   resetTransition().
>   It can be defined in an XML file with the
>   <transition> element. Each Drawable in the transition is defined in a
>   nested <item>

You can find many examples on line, **[here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html)** is one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/first_image" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/second_image" />
</transition>
```

and the code

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
final ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    if (button.isChecked()) {
      drawable.startTransition(500);
    } else {
      drawable.reverseTransition(500);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but, this answer not fulfill my requirement i want to warp image object not to change image using touch...

Comment: @Roadies It is expected for you do a little work too, the example is for a button, but if you read the documentation I linked to, you will understand the class is aimed at drawables in general. you have to write your own code around your drawables.

Comment: @Roadies Since what you want is not morphing, it is warping, this will not help you I think. You should edit your question and the title as well.

Answer (score -1):

This could be achieved by OpenCV so give a try to [this](http://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code%20.)