# How to integrate java morph library in android?

Tags: android, image-processing

i want to develop android app like this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779669/how-to-morphing-on-image-in-android)

But how to integrate java morph library in android..

if you have any example link please paste it here..

[Java morph library](https://code.google.com/p/javamorph/)

thanks in advance

Comment: i am working on something similar. can you tell me if you got any luck?